# git push subdirectory up on pushing to github?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to sync my github code with the live webserver whenever I am pushing to the master.

so when I `git push origin master` to push my code onto github, I also want to push **only** a subdirectory, to the server.

currently I do it via `git subtree push --prefix dist origin master`, where **dist** is the subdirectoy that goes on to the live server.

can I add a hook whenever I push to also do this `git subtree push --prefix dist origin master`?

or is there an even easier way to do this?

my live webserer git-reporsitory is just a bare gitfolder which got it's `GIT_WORKING_TREE` set to the `DocumentRoot` and then `git checkout -f`

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no hook for the `git push` command. To the best of my knowledge, what you are doing seems to be the right thing to do.